# Download image from URL with parameters to device using cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Tags: cordova, meteor, ngcordova

I'm trying to download an image from a server using **MeteorJS/ngCordova/cordova-plugin-file-transfer**

My URL has additional parameters:

```
https://www.myserver.com/files/lkjsdlgjlsd/myImage.jpeg?store=originals
```

When calling `fileTransfer.download(...)` using this url I get the error code

```
1 = FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR
```

However if I only use

```
https://www.myserver.com/files/lkjsdlgjlsd/myImage.jpeg
```

without the additional parameter the download succeeded (but I don't receive the data I'm interested in).

Is there a way to download from such a url with parameters to a cordova-device using ngCordova/ionic or another library?

Comment: Have you tried encoding the URL first? Like so: `var encoded = encodeURI("https://www.myserver.com/files/lkjsdlgjlsd/myImage.jpeg?store=originals"); fileTransfer.download(encoded, ...)`

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the issue. It was the permission to write on the filesystem. Thus, the FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR corresponds to the file to write, and not the file to download...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue: It was the permission to write on the filesystem. Thus, the FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR corresponds to the file to write, and not the file to download (See body property in FileTransferError object).